# Overlay Shapefile onto Geotiff

Tags: raster, vector, geotiff-tiff

I have a Geotiff map and I want to overlay a Shapefile onto it. Ideally I want to specify a 'nice' style for the polygons e.g. have them opaque (for now all polygons should be the same).

I want to print it so I don't want any resampling etc. going on.

How can I accomplish this?

edit: To add a little background: I generated Maps from Openstreetmap using Maperitive. I want to overlay Polygons from Shapefiles to visualize buildings in contrast to the osm buildings. I do not want to resize or resample the maps themselves as the workflow is adjusted exactly for these image sizes. I already converted coordinate systems of raster- and vector files so both are of the same type.

Comment: Overlay in a Web Page or GIS application? This information is important if you want a good answer.

Comment: GIS Application (QGIS, GDAL, etc.). I tried it via the printing Dialog in QGIS but it will resample the graphic and look fuzzy in the final image. I want something like gdal_rasterize but with the ability to specify opaqueness and have nice colors.